# Using PhoneGap features on remote Website possible without iframe?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, cordova

my question is, if it will be possible to use native phonegap feature access from a remote website, without using an iframe.

My current solution looks like this:
If the app is started index.html with the iframe is loaded. When the 'deviceReady' event is fired the 'src' of the iframe is set to the remote website, and it is shown in the iframe. I can navigate through the website as usual. To navigate back in the history of the iframe i listen to the 'backbutton' event in the index.js file and send a postMessage to the iframe to go history back. This is my work-a-round to use the phonegap functionality for the external website.
I have full control over the remote website and can change code there.

The main problem is the "look and feel" of this iframe. The layout and performance of the iframe is not consistent and very poor.

So my question is, if there is any other solution to have access to the phonegap plugins without using the iframe.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

InAppBrowser

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

You can `executeScript`, too.

This is an exteranl WebView, and full Screen, so much different than iFrame.

Comment: I added the phonegap.js and/or the cordova.js to the remote server and it did not work. So it wont work in the inAppBrowser either, doesn't it? What must I add to have "menubutton" or "backbutton" functionality? And there is a NOTE: The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and cannot access Cordova APIs.

Comment: What do you mean by `add phonegap to the remote server`? and yes, as I mentioned, it's basically an external WebView so it behaves like a standard webBrowswer. You can 'push' executeScript, but to obtain anyfeedback from the WebView is very hard to do, perhaps unless using localStorage, it's not possible. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I added the cordova.js file to the remote server and it is included in every single page. I set JavaScriptEnabled = true to the webview. Now the two buttons work fine, but I have no access to the phonegap API at all. Is it possible to get access to that API from the external page (which include cordova.js) in the WebView?